# r Distinct objects into n Distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics

My book contains the following 3 rules:

```
1.Each box can hold at most 1 object:
```

Ans: nPr

So if there are 5 items, first box got 5 choices, 2nd box got 4 choices and so on.

```
2. Each box can hold any number of objects:
```

**(I don't understand. How do i picture this?)**

Ans: n^r

```
3. Each box can hold any number of objects and order matters:
```

**(I don't understand. How do i picture this?)**

Ans: (n + r − 1)!/(n − 1)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, think of what choices each *ball* has instead of each box is probably easier.

For the first problem, the first ball has $n$ options, the second ball $n-1$, and so on, giving $_nP_r$ different options.

For the second problem, same thinking, but this time the number of options for each ball does not decrease. So first ball has $n$ options, second ball has $n$ options, and so on.

For the third, think that the boxes are so narrow that the balls must be stacked top of one another. This is how I think about the calculation: Take out box number one and set it aside. Now shuffle all balls and the rest of the boxes together. This can be done in $(n+r-1)$ ways. For each box, take the balls that are after it, but before the next box, and put them in in the order they are. The balls that are before any boxes you put into box number one. Finally, the same configuration can be reached one way for each order the boxes are in, do we need to divide by $(n-1)!$.

Comment: for part 3 is it possible to illustrate using bars and stars method?

Comment: @Rstyle Yes, but the stars are distinguishable. So you get $_{n+r-1}C_{n-1}\cdot r!$, which is exactly the same result. That's actually an easier solution, note that I think about it.